# How to repair accidentally removed solder pad?

Tags: pcb, soldering, keyboard

Disclaimer: Pardon my lack of knowledge on the following

So while I was trying to de-solder a keyboard switch I accidentally removed the solder pad (top arrow) and not only that lost it as well in the process... Perhaps the damage is done but is there a way to fix this and to test the keyboard switch before re-soldering? Right now there is no response by just "attaching" the key to the board and pressing... any ideas or direction on to how I could fix this?

Thanks a bunch!

[image]

Comment: You need an electrical connection. I would probably try removing the soldermask on the trace that connects to it and make a solder bridge to the exposed copper. Be very careful those traces are incredibly easy to break and be careful not to solder to the plane next to the trace.

Comment: Tack wire to the remaining track ... through the hole to pad or track on the other side.

Comment: I find it's usually easier to trace back to whatever component connects to that pad and tie the wire there.  Trying to solder to that 10mil copper trace directly isn't going to be easy nor particularly reliable. The component itself usually presents a bigger target for your jumper wire.    ALso, for bonus points, after you get a jumper wire soldered down, tack the wire to the PCB with some hot-melt glue to immobilize it.  DON'T put glue on the ends of the wire where it's soldered (in case you have to move it someday), but DO tack it down if a few spots (depends on the length of the wire.)

Comment: run a wire from the switch to the via that is NW of Z15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the button back in, solder the one pin to the existing pad.

From the other pin, solder a short wire to the free pad of part Z13 there to the left of the destroyed hole.

If you manage to kill that pad, then follow the trace across the board.  Somewhere over to the right, it will go into a hole (called a "via.")  Scrape the green paint off of the via, and solder a wire to the via and the pin of the button.

If you kill the via, flip the board over and find the other side of the via.  Scrape clean, solder a wire, etc.

You can do that as long as you can trace the trace and find something connected to it.  Eventually, you will reach the end of the line and can't go any further.  At that point, the button can't be fixed at all.

Comment: Followed exactly that and surprisingly to my abysmal skills I did it quite well as per your guidance! Thanks!